# FSA No 10 - Upgrade

Tags: headset

I have an FSA no 10 headset.

I seem to need new bearings every 4 to 6 months I normally replace the whole headeset as its fairly cheap.

However this time I brought some caged bearings from Halfords, my headset just grinds now (the bearing must have been the wrong size).

So I'm wondering if the is an alternative that I can use with sealed bearings as I assume they would last longer?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait a second. You need to replace your headset bearings two or three times a year? I leave that level of maintenance to the bike shop but I don't recall them _ever_ telling me that I need to replace the headset bearings. Either I'm very lucky or you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm riding at least 70 miles a week, its just wear and tear, you should carry on getting the lbs to do your bike, if it works for you, thank you for your reply.

Comment: OK, but I'm cycling 35-50 miles per week. Sheldon says "Headsets are pretty durable, and hardly ever need to be serviced if your bicycle has a front fender" so I wonder if my front fender is the explanation of our very different experiences.

Comment: I suspect that the front fender helps a lot, less water going g up the fork, I'm fairly sure the no 10 are supposed to be cheap throwaway / replaceable

Comment: Yeah. And I'm sorry if you were upset by my initial phrasing. I should have said something along the lines of "... or you have a more fundamental underlying problem."

Comment: Headsets usually last for the life of the bike.  You have something wrong.  Perhaps the races are installed cockeyed or some such.

Comment: (What symptoms do you get of the headset bearings wearing out???)

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about bicycles is that most parts are standard. The not so nice thing is that there are quite many standards to choose from.

Fortunately there is only one type of FSA No 10: 1 1/8 inch zero stack internal. It can be replaced with any headset with the magic words "1 1/8 inch zero stack internal". There are many models to choose from, pick one that fits your budget and is available.

Note that internal and integrated are different things. Earlier version of this answer said integrated, which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not - A sealed bearing is a different shape to bearings intended to be loose or in a cage.  So the only way to fit sealed bearings would be to replace the cup/cone parts with something that has more space and no bearing surface.

I'm not familiar with your exact headset sorry, but ~4 monthly replacement does seem excessively frequent.  If you're leaving the bike outside in the weather that will contribute to faster deterioration like this.

Comment: Yeah I leave it out in the rain, when I'm working or gone shopping etc.. I did change my disk breaks to a larger 190 rotor I wonder if the additional breaking force gives additional wear and tear? Have been looking at the comments on chain reaction it seems a no 9 might fit, but the stack height is different does that mean I just need more spacers?